# How can i select fields ApprovedBy and Time from the table?

Tags: mysql

```
id   old   Name   SentBy    ApprovedBy     Time     Fee
1   love   love   seyi       jayjay        1:00pm   200
2   love   love   seyi       smith         1:05pm   200
```

In this table,there is a fraud! Column 'SentBy' sent two request at 1pm and 1:05pm and approved by jay and smith on Column 'ApprovedBy' with the same 'fee' of 200. how do i determine who really approved the request and how many times it was sent?

Comment: what do you mean by select? `SELECT ApprovedBy, Time FROM TableName` or `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ApproveBy = '' AND Time =''` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ApprovedBy, Time FROM <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple select query

```
Select ApprovedBy,Time From YourTablename
```